# Посоветуйте библиотеку для асинхронных запросов, аналог requests

Tags: python, requests, asyncio, асинхронность, поиск-библиотек

В общем пишу телеграм бота и использую там библиотеку requests, оказалось что она не работает в асинхроне и ищу аналог. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, библиотеку для получения кода страницы, которая будет работать в асинхроне

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне известно <s>две</s>три таких библиотеки:

### [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp)

Позволяет реализовывать как асинхронный клиенты, так и асинхронные серверы. Пример асинхронного http запроса (скопировано из документации: [Client Quickstart](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html)):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

asyncio.run(main())
```

### [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx)

Только клиент, может использоваться для синхронных и асинхронных http запросов. Пример асинхронного запроса:

```
import asyncio
import httpx

async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get('https://www.example.com/')
        print(response)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Опять же, пример взят из документации: [Async Support](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/)

### [niquests](https://github.com/jawah/niquests)

Форк requests c дополнительными фичами, в том числе с поддержкой асинхронности.

Пример кода с асинхронностью на основе пример из readme:

```
import niquests
import asyncio


async def main():
    s = niquests.AsyncSession()
    r = await s.get('https://pie.dev/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=('user', 'pass'), stream=True)
    print(r)
    print(await r.json())


asyncio.run(main())
```

Сессию также можно использовать как менеджер контекста, аналогично предыдущим библиотекам:

```
    async with niquests.AsyncSession() as s:
        r = await s.get('https://pie.dev/basic-auth/user/pass', auth=('user', 'pass'), stream=True)
        print(r)
        print(await r.json())
```

Документация: [Quickstart - Async session](https://niquests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#async-session) (и разделы ниже).